# Win32 Application Programming C++, Error with parameter Type LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, winapi

I am constructing a program using the Win32 Application on Visual Studio 2013. From the tutorials I have read, I know this following code is correct, but I don't know where to change the parameter type to read the following:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "Edit", "",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL |
        ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 50, 100, 300, 300, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_EDIT_BOX, 
        NULL, NULL);
```

The compiler highlights "Edit" and gives me this error:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'HWND CreateWindowExW(DWORD,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,DWORD,int,int,int,int,HWND,HMENU,HINSTANCE,LPVOID)' : **cannot convert argument 2 from 'const char [5]' to 'LPCWSTR'**

Comment: have you tried L"Edit" in argument 2?

Comment: and L"" in argument 3.

Comment: This will help: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/76252/what-are-tchar-wchar-lpstr-lpwstr-lpctstr-etc

Answer (score 9):

You are compiling with `UNICODE` defined. That means that `CreateWindowEx` is an alias for `CreateWindowExW`, the wide character version. Either:

1. Supply wide character text, or
2. Call `CreateWindowExA`, or
3. Compile for ANSI.

Personally I would suggest option 1. Your code would become:

```
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"Edit", L"",
  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL, 
  50, 100, 300, 300, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_EDIT_BOX, NULL, NULL);
```

The `L` prefix to your string literals is used to specify a wide character literal.

Comment: @UysofSpades Do you need any more help? Or is this question answered?

Comment: If you are going to hard-code Unicode text, then you need to call `CreateWindowExW()` instead of `CreateWindowEx()`. Otherwise, if you continue calling `CreateWindowEx()` then you need to use the `TEXT()` macro when passing literals.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is complaining about `CreateWindowExW()` but your code is calling `CreateWindowEx()`.  That means your project is being compiled with `UNICODE` defined.  In which case, `CreateWindowEx()` maps to `CreateWindowExW()`, which expects wide (`wchar_t*`) data, but you are passing it narrow (`char*`) data instead, hence the error.

You need to either:

1. call `CreateWindowExW()` directly, and prefix the literals with `L` to make them wide instead of narrow:

   ```
   hEdit = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"Edit", L"", ...);
   ```
2. continue calling `CreateWindowEx()` but wrap literals with the `TEXT()` macro so it will make them narrow or wide for you based on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not:

   ```
   hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("Edit"), TEXT(""), ...);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you need to decide what type of project you are trying to create with regard to character set. You have at least four options for project type

1. Project that uses regular (narrow) characters only (`char`)
2. Project that uses wide characters only (`wchar_t`)
3. "Transformer" project that can be easily compiled as either type 1 or type 2 by a simple change in project settings
4. Project that freely mixes narrow and wide characters

This is the decision that you have to make first. There's no point in proceeding before you make that decision.

Now, depending on the choice you made, you should proceed as follows

1. Regular `char` project

   - Go to project settings and set "Character Set" to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set"
   - In your code use regular (narrow) string and character literals: `"Edit"`, `'A'` etc.
   - Use regular `char`, `char [N]`, `char *` and `std::string` types to work with characters and strings
   - Use narrow versions of standard library functions: `printf`, `strcpy` etc.
   - Use either "normal" names to call Windows API functions: `CreateWindowEx`, or their narrow names: `CreateWindowExA` (whichever you like better)
2. Wide `wchar_t` project

   - Go to project settings and set "Character Set" to "Use Unicode Character Set"
   - In your code explicitly use wide string and character literals: `L"Edit"`, `L'A'` etc.
   - Use wide `wchar_t`, `wchar_t [N]`, `wchar_t *` and `std::wstring` types to work with characters and strings
   - Use wide versions of standard library functions: `wprintf`, `wcscpy` etc.
   - Use either "normal" names to call Windows API functions: `CreateWindowEx`, or their wide names: `CreateWindowExW` (whichever you like better)
3. "Transformer" project

   - Include `<tchar.h>` into every translation unit
   - In your code always explicitly use macro `_T` with string and character literals: `_T("Edit")`, `_T('A')` etc.
   - Use `TCHAR`, `TCHAR [N]`, `TCHAR *` and `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` types to work with characters and strings
   - Use "transformer" versions of standard library functions: `_tprintf`, `_tcscpy` etc.
   - Use "normal" names to call Windows API functions: `CreateWindowEx`
      
      
     With this kind of project, if you do everything properly, you will be able to automatically switch between type 1 and type 2 by simply changing the "Character Set" setting in project settings.
4. Mix-and-match project

   - Use whatever type of character you prefer (narrow or wide) in each specific context, but remember to call the proper version of standard library and Windows API function for each character type. In some cases, when narrow and wide contexts meet, you will have to perform conversions between narrow and wide character types.

Of course, if you started a project of type 1 or type 2, you can always turn it into a project of type 4 by starting to mix character types. But if you need a type 3 project, it is a good idea to stick to its principles from the very beginning (converting to type 3 later is a very laborious process).

---

It is not immediately obvious what you are trying to do in your project. But a wild guess would be that you are trying to build a type 1 project. In that case all you need to do to fix the problem is go to project settings and set "Character Set" to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set".

Answer (score 0):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
switch (Message){   
case WM_PAINT:
    break;
case WM_CREATE:

    break;

case WM_DESTROY:

    return 0;

default:

    if (IsWindowUnicode(hWnd))
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    else
        return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    break;
}
return 0;}
```